# Unable to access struct data

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kmalloc

In the header file:

```
typedef struct {
char* a;         
int allowed;

struct suit {
        struct t {
                char* option;
                int count;      
        } t;

        struct inner {
                char* option; 
                int count;      
        } inner;        
} suit;
} contain;

typedef struct {
       contain info;
} query_arg_t;
```

In the kernel module,

// initialize

```
static const contain _vector = { 
.a = "John",
.allowed = 1,
.suit = {
    .t = {
        .option = "ON",
        .count = 7
    },
    .inner = {
        .option = "OFF (*)",
        .count = 7
    }           
}
};
```

However, as we try:

```
query_arg_t q;

    q.info = kmalloc(sizeof(_vector), GFP_KERNEL);
```

We will get this error:
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘contain’ from type ‘void *’

The above error is solved by @SunEric and @Sakthi Kumar.

```
         q.info = kmalloc(sizeof(_vector), GFP_KERNEL);
        memcpy(&(q.info), &(_vector), sizeof(_vector));
```

It seems ok now.
It builds but when it runs to that part, it states that the  **kernel stack is corrupted**.
after trying to execute:

```
     printf("option: %s \n", q.info->suit.t.option); 
     printf("option: %s \n", q.info->suit.t.option);
```

[Updated: Solved]

@Sakthi Kumar solved it by:

```
   //removing kmalloc
   // commenting out: q.info = &_vector;
   memcpy(&(q.info), &(_vector), sizeof(_vector));

printf("option: %s \n", q.info.suit.t.option);
printf("option: %s \n", q.info.suit.inner.option);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure to be of the form

```
typedef struct {
       contain *info;
} query_arg_t;
```

You are trying to assign a pointer (`kmalloc` returns `void *`) to a `struct` variable (`contain`).

Comment: Thank you, @Sakthi Kumar. Could you also guide me on the following question emended above?

Comment: @Babbit since `info` is a pointer you have to access it like `printf("option: %s \n", q.info->suit.t.option);`

Comment: It builds but when it runs to that part, it states some kernel stack problem.

Comment: @Babbit I think you do not have to `kmalloc` since u already have the `_vector` as `static`, u can try this `q.info = &_vector`. remove the `kmalloc` and change the next statement to the one mentioned and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: The kernel is not crashing anymore, but the 2 lines is not printing.

 printf("option: %s \n", q.info->suit.t.option);
 printf("option: %s \n", q.info->suit.inner.option);

Comment: @Babbit Well, this seems that the pointers in the `struct` is making problems. can u plz make all the `char *` to say `char a[20]` or the max num of chars required and check this?

Comment: I just did a dmesg. It states "[20868.612110] query_app[5818]: segfault at ffffffffa032c06c ip 00007fa9b6ccb3b1 sp 00007fff6a624120 error 5 in libc-2.15.so[7fa9b6c80000+1b5000]".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47079/discussion-between-sakthi-kumar-and-babbit)

Answer (score 2):

`void * kmalloc (size_t size, int flags);`

`kmalloc` returns type `void *` which you are trying to assign to `contain` is in-correct.

Change to,

```
typedef struct {
   contain *info; // info is a pointer to struct contain
} query_arg_t;

query_arg_t q;
q.info = kmalloc(sizeof(_vector), GFP_KERNEL);
```

Answer to followup question:

`q.info` is a pointer to structure pointing to `contain`. You need array operator `->` to access structure members through pointer. So try below options to access `info` as,

```
q.info->stat.t.option
```

Or

```
(*q.info).stat.t.option
```

Comment: Thank you, @SunEric. Could you also guide me on the following question emended above?

Answer (score 0):

The C language specification prohibits declaring struct types inside other structs without declaring a member of that type.

Comment: can you show me how to remedy it? 
It only failed at the kmalloc.